# PHP 8 equivalent of getter or setter for public properties

Tags: php, class

I'm creating a base class in PHP 8 in which I want to have a $isDirty private property.
I'd prefer the classes that extend the base class to be able to use public properties so that they will show up in the IDE.
However, I want to be able to set the $isDirty variable any time a public property is set or changed.
I've been able to update the $isDirty by using the __set magic method but only if the inheriting class properties are protected or private. However, making them protected or private prevents the IDE autocompletion from working.
Is there a way I can "inject" my method to set one variable when another is set without changing that variable's scope from public to protected?

Comment: Having public properties can cause all sorts of problems, be careful when making that sort of decision.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHPDoc to declare the property on the class. Most IDEs will recognize it and autocomplete will work.

```
/**
  * @property boolean $isDirty
  */
class Something {
    private $isDirty;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by using a checksum variable and setting it in the constructor, and after loading, saving, or updating to the database.  Here is the proof of concept:

```
Class Foo {
    public string $checksum = '';

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->checksum = self::getChecksum();
    }

    public function getChecksum() : string {
        $values = '';
        foreach ($this as $key => $value) {
            if($key !== "checksum")
                $values.= "$key=>$value,";
        }
        return md5($values);
    }
}

class Bar extends Foo {
    public string $name;
}

$a = new Bar();
echo "<p>A checksum: ".$a->checksum."</p>";
echo "<p>getChecksum:".$a->getChecksum()."</p>";
$a->name = "Andrew";
echo "<p>Checksum after setting name:".$a->getChecksum()."</p>";
```